# drawer with logout in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am facing one issue in my drawer. I am looking for some help in this. People who are using react navigation 5 version.

i am using the latest react navigation version and my code for custom drawer is below

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  //

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Logout"   onPress={()=>
              Alert.alert(
                'Log out',
                'Do you want to logout?',
                [
                  {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {return null}},
                  {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => {
                    AsyncStorage.clear();
                    //props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                  }},
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
              ) 


      } />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

And my route.js is mentioned below.

```
  export default function Routes(username, password) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
      const Stack = createStackNavigator();
      const [loader, setloader] = useState('');
      const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        (prevState, action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                userToken: action.token,
                isLoading: false,
              };
            case 'SIGN_IN':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: false,
                userToken: action.token,
              };
            case 'SIGN_OUT':
              return {
                ...prevState,
                isSignout: true,
                userToken: undefined,
              };
          }
        },
        {
          isLoading: true,
          isSignout: false,
          userToken: null,
        },
      );

      React.useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
        const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
          let userToken;

          try {
            userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@kiklee-user-id');
          } catch (e) {
            // Restoring token failed
          }

          // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps

          // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
          // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
          dispatch({type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken});
        };

        bootstrapAsync();
      }, []);

      const authContext = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
          signIn: async data => {
            try {
              let config_api_url = Config.api_login_url;
              if (data.username === '' && data.password === '') {
                Alert.alert(
                  'Error : ',
                  'Please enter your email address and password.',
                );
              } else if (data.username === '') {
                Alert.alert('Error : ', 'Please enter your email address.');
              } else if (
                !(data.username === '') &&
                Validate.isEmailValid(data.username) === true
              ) {
                Alert.alert('Error : ', 'Please enter the correct email address.');
              } else if (password.length < 5) {
                Alert.alert(
                  'Error : ',
                  'Please enter your password with a minimum length of 5.',
                );
              } else {
                // seterror(''); //empty all errors
                setloader(true);

                await fetch(config_api_url, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: data.username,
                    password: data.password,
                  }),
                  headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                })
                  .then(response => response.text())
                  .then(async responseData => {
                    // parse the json values
                    var responsevalue = JSON.parse(responseData);
                    if (responsevalue.login_status === 'Active') {
                      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@kiklee-user-id');
                      await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                        '@kiklee-user-id',
                        responsevalue.id.toString(),
                      );
                      // const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@kiklee-user-id');
                      dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token'});
                      setloader(false);
                      // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
                    } else if (responsevalue.login_status == 'Deactive') {
                      Alert.alert('Error : ', 'Userid is deactive.');
                      setloader(false);
                    } else {
                      Alert.alert('Error : ', 'Invalid username or password.');
                      setloader(false);
                    }
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    Alert.alert(err);
                  });
              }
            } catch (e) {
              // saving error
              Alert.alert('Please try your login after some time.');
            }
          },
          signOut: async () => {

            AsyncStorage.removeItem('@kiklee-user-id');
            dispatch({type: 'SIGN_OUT'});
          },
          signUp: async data => {
            dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token'});
          },
        }),
        [],
      );

      if (state.isLoading) {
        // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
        return <SplashScreen />;
      }

      // Loader
      if (loader == true) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Spinner
              visible={true}
              textContent={'Loading...'}
              textStyle={styles.spinnerTextStyle}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            {state.userToken == null ? (
              <>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={{
                      headerShown: false,
                      animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
                    }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="Privacy"
                    component={Privacy}
                    options={{headerShown: false}}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="ForgetPassword"
                    component={ForgetPassword}
                    options={{headerShown: true}}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="SignUp"
                    component={Signup}
                    options={{headerShown: false}}
                  />
                </Stack.Navigator>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <Drawer.Navigator
                  initialRouteName="Dashboard"
                  drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent(props)}>
                  <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={MainRoot} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
              </>
            )}
          </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
    }
```

i can call authcontext inside the custom drawer because it will display a error called "Hooks rule"

i am looking for a help only with react navigation 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `const Stack = createStackNavigator();` above the `Routes` component.

Your `useState` and `useReducer` hooks need to come first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ,but eventually I created a work around because I tried passing the function as props from different roots and when i logged props from the customer drawer item , it was undefined... so that lead me to a previous solution that I had used with react navigation v4.

Solution:

create your own component for signing out and other functionalities like links etc.

```
const DrawerMeta = () => {
  const { signOut } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
      <Button
        onPress={async () => {
          await signOut();
        }}
        title="sign out"

      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

insert into your drawer component

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  //

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerMeta />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
    
  );
}
```